# Select most recent record from table

Tags: visual-studio-2012, sql-server-2012

```
Private Sub Default__Load(ByVal Sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)     Handles MyBase.Load

    Dim conn As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection("datasource=xxx;database=xxx;uid=xxx;pwd=xxx;")
    Dim cmd As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand("SELECT ID FROM Table WHERE DateTimeCreated = ???????????", conn)

    conn.Open()
    Dim ID As String = Convert.ToString(cmd.ExecuteScalar())
    conn.Close()


    lblID.Text = ID

End Sub
```

Basically I need something to replace the ???????? that brings the most recently created ID (the ID is a uniqueidentifier)

I'm sure it's really simple, though I may be setting the whole thing out wrong.

Comment: Can you edit the schema by adding an identity column?

Comment: I suppose if there was no easy way I could, but it would involve recreating the table and there are already quite a few values in there so if I can avoid it it would be great

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use something like this there in order to get the latest ID

```
(SELECT TOP 1 ID FROM table
ORDER BY DateTimeCreated DESC)
```

In place of your ????? of course.

EDITED

Comment: the ID is a uniqueidentifier, so it's a random 16 digit code, not 1,2,3 in order unfortunately

Comment: Apologies, that was me making assumptions. I have made an edit assuming your datetimecreated field is a datetime field?

Comment: I think it's sysdate, but I will try this